# How to use F#'s headOrDefault on an empty array?

Tags: .net, linq, f#

I want to test the headOrDefault in F# on an empty array, which is supposed to work like FirstOrDefault in C#. So I typed in this code:

```
let arr = []

let res = query {
    for e in arr do
    select e
    headOrDefault
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}", (res = null))
```

I would expect `res` to get the value null.

But this code doesn't even compile. I get this compile error:

*Inner generic functions are not permitted in quoted expressions. Consider adding some type constraints until this function is no longer generic.*

The compiler underlines `arr` in this line as the problem:

for e in ***arr*** do

Why won't this compile, and how can I get it to work (using headOrDefault)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[] is not an array, it is a list, but it doesn't matter much in this case as both arrays and lists are enumerable. If you want an empty array then you should use [||] or Array.empty.

The error you get is because your enumerable is of a generic type, i.e. the compiler doesn't know what type of elements that should go into your list/array.
If you want a list of System.Object the following works (replace System.Object with the type of list you want, but you must specify something as a generic list is not allowed):

```
let emptyarr:System.Object list = []
let res = query {
    for e in emptyarr do
    select e
    headOrDefault
}
System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", (res = null))
```

Comment: also, there's the `obj` type alias you can use instead of `System.Object`.

Comment: You can also use `List.empty<obj>`

Answer (score 1):

Neatest way is `let arr = [] : obj list`, I think.